# why git checkout automatically generate a "swp" file?

Tags: git, vim

I have modified a file, named index.html
then I run

```
git checkout .
```

which should rollback my modification...

It works well, but a new .index.html.swp file is created...

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That file isn't created by git, it is a scratch file created by vim when it edits a file.

There are two likely causes for this:

1. You have a file open in vim at the time you run the command, and noticing that is a side-effect.
2. You have that file committed to the repository, so git puts it where it should.